# CSS set similar items to the same height as the tallest item on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of products set up on my site with an image and a description inside a `<span>` tag like below.

However I want them all to be a uniform size no matter what length the paragraph is.

I can set a height for it but then the smaller ones will all have a huge gap which I don't want as I have different Categories set up and some of them have really long or really short descriptions.

If I can get a way to set a height based on the longest on the screen at the time that would be great because at least the ones in the same category should have close enough to the same length that it won't make too much of a difference

```css
span{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:110px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
p{
  width:90%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>some text</p>
</span>
<span>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
</span>
<span>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>some text</p>
</span>
```

Comment: why not to use tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will handle this for you automatically! Put all of your `span` in a container with `display: flex` set:

```css
span{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:110px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
p{
  width:90%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
    <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
    <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
    <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
    <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>some text</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment when I use flex and these all have a fixed width they all try to stay on the same line and overflow off screen

Comment: @PaddyHallihan You need to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to your `.container` to wrap the children.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Updated answer with multiple children that wrap

Comment: Cheers thanks a million :) You hardly know of a way to center them all then with the wrap?

Comment: @PaddyHallihan What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a simple script to determine the maximum height of the images. I then set this height to all other elements. Here is the code:

```js
// array of all elements
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')];

// determine the maximum of all heights
const heights = elements.map((e) => e.offsetHeight);
const maxHeight = Math.max(...heights);

// set the all heights to the maximum value
elements.forEach((e) => e.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`);
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<span class="image">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>some text</p>
</span>
<span>
<img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
</span>
<span>
<img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<p>some text</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just curious, what does the spread do in this example? `elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')]` vs `elements = document.querySelectorAll('span')`. Wouldn't both return an array of elements?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda, the former returns an `Array` of `HTMLElement`s, the latter returns a `NodeList` of `Node`s. By using the `[...document.querySelectorAll('span')]` syntax I'm able to then call methods like `map()`, `forEach()` since it's an `Array`. I prefer that than using a `for` loop to access the elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ideal use-case for flex box.

A couple great resources are

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Here's the basic idea that you could adapt to your needs:

```css
.items{
  display:flex;
}
.item{
 border: 1px dashed #f00;
 flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vitae orci dui. Donec urna erat, blandit vitae placerat id, efficitur et libero. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vitae orci dui. Donec urna erat, blandit vitae placerat id, <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note, setting `flex: 1` on the children isn't needed for this case!

Comment: Actually `flex:1` is needed otherwise they won't be of even width.

Comment: For consistent widths yes, but OP wants consistent heights which can be achieved without `flex: 1` on the children.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Bootstrap v4` `row` and `col` classes.

*Press `Full Page` whenever you run the snippet to see the result.*

Example:

---

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>some text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>some text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>some text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>a really really really really really really really really really really long bit of text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <p>some text</p>
      </span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Using `Bootstrap` basically does this automatically for you and all I did with the `CSS` was added `height: 100%;` in `span` tag.

Comment: Bootstrap wasn't included in the list of tags by the OP.

Comment: Okay. At the least, he will know that he can also use Bootstrap to overcome his problem too.